# Amazon Product JSON document query

Tags: angularjs, json, amazon-web-services

using aws-lib nodejs module to access Amazon affiliate API retrieval code here:

```
prodAdv.call("ItemLookup", {ItemId: "B010T6D39O , B0136JONG8", ResponseGroup: "Images,ItemAttributes,Offers"}, function(err, result) {
res.send(JSON.stringify(result));    
})
```

I receive this http://pastebin.com/A1Uy5nE0 at the URL of /amazon. I then use

```
<div ng-repeat="amazon in amazon">  
   {{amazon.Item}}
</div>
```

To display all the data, but am unable to select specific data, and when trying to filter the with

`| filter:{}`

I get an error stating the document is in the wrong format. It might be the case where I cannot use this data or method of retrieving data. I need to be able to call amazon.LowestNewPrice or amazon.LargeImage but cannot.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in your html to filter**

```
<div ng-repeat="amazon in amazon | filter:{ Name  : "ResponseGroup"})>  
   {{amazon.Item}}
</div>
```

**for filtering nested properties**

```
<div ng-repeat="amazon in amazon | 
 filter:{ property.subproperty:filterValue})>  
 {{amazon.Item}}
</div>
```